# C# Local DB Application to SQL Server Application

Tags: c#, database

I created a simple application that consists in a DataGridView that is bind to a local database in my computer. I used a DataSet, a Binding Source and a Table Adapter to do this. The application has some buttons to Insert, Delete and Edit Rows. Simple stuff.

I want to know if there is any way of connecting, this same application, to a SQL Server Database (instead of localdatabase), and if so what do i have to change in my actual code?

The connection String? The Data Source?...

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Once your database is on the remote server, and you've worked out the authentication and so on, chances are the main change is the connection string - unless its a different version..

Answer (score 0):

You have to rewrite/create your connection string, what you can find in your project root in the 'App.Config'  ( or 'Web.Config' in mvc for example ) file. Now since you provide no code for, us, we can't be sure how it's done.

So after you get your db up and running, you either generate a new connection string if you used some kind of wizard for the dataset. Or you have to rewrite in your App.Config, just google 'connection strings' or http://www.connectionstrings.com/ would be a good place to start.

I can help you with the string, but it's depend on the db, the connection, the authentication, and some other parameters, so i need to know your exact setup for further help. But luckily for you there are plenty of help already exist on the net.